# How does the Ticket To Ride:1910 expansion change the original game?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

- What does the expansion contain?
- What are the different ways to play with it?
- How is each different from playing without the expansion?
- Is there anything else I should know about the expansion before buying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1910**
The primary mechanical change is an alternate set of tickets, and there is also an additional bonus score condition.

The tickets work exactly the same way as normal, but it's a different set. They may also be combined into a single large ticket deck.

The standard bonus condition is longest route; the new one is most completed tickets. Both have the same value, and are often not the same person.

Since I've only played 1910 online, I can't speak to the card size issue.

**Europe 1912**, the comparable expansion for Ticket to Ride: Europe, likewise has replacement tickets and the most routes bonus, but instead of adding full size cards, instead adds a "depot" mechanism, which results in the trains deck being depleted sooner and more cards being out of play. While the tickets are not cross-compatible, the depots are. Since TTRE also has separate long route cards, 1912 also adds 6 more, to a total of 12.

Answer (score 3):

I'll let someone else explain the expansion options, I just want to list the most important change.

### Normal Size Cards

Comment: +1'd, they make such a difference.  It's a bit of a crime that they weren't standard to the core set...